# dispatch_async block on main queue is never execeuted

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have an app that uses a connection queue that handles the connections on a background thread.  Each connection sends a JSON post, then when it receives a success, saves some objects into coredata.

Once all connections are complete, i call a `dispatch_async` on the main thread to call a `finished` method.

However, under very specific conditions of data im sending/saving, I've noticed the `dispatch_async` block to the main thread never gets called, and the app screen freezes, all execution stops, and the app sits idle with a frozen screen. processing power according to xcode is 0%.

Here is method with the block that fails.

```
- (void)connectionDidComplete
{
    _completeConnections++;

    _syncProgress = (float)_completeConnections / (float)_totalConnections;

    dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^(void) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SyncQueueDidUpdateNotification object:nil];
    }); <-- this dispatch works

    if (_completeConnections == _totalConnections)
    {
        // clear unsynced data
        NSArray *syncedObjects = [SyncObject completedSyncObjects];

        if (syncedObjects.count > 0)
        {
            for (SyncObject *syncObject in syncedObjects)
            {
                [syncObject delete];
            }
        }

        //this method saves the current context, then merges this context with the main context right after
        [[VS_CoreDataManager sharedManager] saveManagedObjectContextAndWait:managedObjectContext];

        // cleanup the thread's context
        [[VS_CoreDataManager sharedManager] unRegisterManagedObjectContextForThread:currentThread];
        managedObjectContext = nil;

        // complete sync
        dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^(void) {
            [self performSelector:@selector(finishSync) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
        }); <-- this dispatch never gets called
    }
}
```

My suspicion is this problem has something to do with saving the context then merging it. And possibly while that is happening its released in the middle of the merge, causing some weird hang up and the dispatch isn't getting executed.  This is just a guess though, and I don't know how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: No idea why the block isn't executed (have you set a break point inside the block or added a debug log message?), but instead of your `dispatch_async` + `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, why not use [`dispatch_after`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/dispatch_after.3.html) instead?

Comment: +1 for does it get inside the block.  Not sure if `completedconnections` equals `totalconnections`.

Comment: ive set a breakpoint in the block, execution does not reach it

Comment: Can you post some code from your saveManagedObjectContextAndWait:?

Comment: does `completedConnections` ever equal `totalConnections`?

Comment: @Putz1103 yes, the line calling dispatch_async gets called (using breakpoints) but the line inside the block does not.

Comment: @Unheilig its a block for the context that locks, then saves the context, all in a try catch.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If the block on the main thread is not executed, then it is because of 1 of 2 reasons.

1. The main thread is blocked;  is not processing any events at all.  Got a while() loop on the main thread?  That'd do it.  A lock?  There you go.
2. The main thread is running a modal run loop inside the outer run loop.    Asynchronous dispatches to the main event loop -- main thread -- won't be processed in this case.

Set a breakpoint on that `dispatch_async()` and see what the main thread is doing (at the point of dispatch the main thread is most likely already in the bad state).

DarkDust's suggestion of using `dispatch_after()` is a good one, but is unlikely to work in that it is almost assuredly the case that your main thread is not processing events when the problem occurs.   I.e. fix the problem, then move to `dispatch_after()` as DarkDust suggests.

Comment: after setting the breakpoint, i looked at the main thread and it is currently executing a fetch request to see how many connections are left in its queue count.  This was fired from a notification that gets sent out in the first dispatch in the OP.  A listener calls the fetch request.

Comment: Another interesting thing is after i hit the dispatch_async line, all threads are wiped out.  Literally all execution everywhere goes away.

Comment: @JMD It sounds like your main thread is truly wedged, then.  Without seeing more code, hard to say exactly where.  Best guess is that your notification handler is making a blocking call into the thread/queue doing the download *and* that thread is blocked waiting for the notification to be fully handled?   I.e. this sounds like a cross-queue deadlock issue.

Comment: I removed the line calling the fetch request and fixed the issue.  So i guess the process of executing the fetch request hangs the main thread enough it cant execute the block.

Comment: This is a very precise answer with a great solution on how to fix the problem! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If your main thread is busy with modal runloop, then you could try

```
CFRunLoopPerformBlock(CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, block
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is a great discussion. I came across this when I had the following code:

```
   dispatch_synch(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        print("I am here")
   }
```

the print code did not execute as I was dispatching a 'synch' block on the serial main thread which caused a dead lock. print was waiting for the dispatch to finish and dispatch was waiting for print to finish. When you dispatch in the main serial queue then you should use dispatch_async. and i guess if you use a concurrent queue then dispatch synch suits better