# dispatch_async not completing block

Tags: ios7, grand-central-dispatch

I'm parsing XML files with the below code and am getting strange behavior. I want the user to be able to queue up multiple files that need to be parsed and have them on a separate thread and completed serially. Everything works as expected IF I dispatch one queue and allow it to finish before clicking the next.

However, if I begin the first and immediately fire another the first queue finishes parsing but does not finish the block by calling the Main Q to make UI updates and the app become unresponsive (though my spinner keeps going). CPU drops to 0% according to Xcode and memory stays constant.

I am using CoreData and creating a new MOC on the respective thread. Again, If I do one at a time it works fine, if I comment out the parsing and just do a loop I can queue things up and it works, starting the next loop after the one before finishes.

This post mentions the main thread being blocked but if I run a repeating timer and just log it out while queue is running all is good.

Reference -->
[dispatch_async block on main queue is never execeuted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120035/dispatch-async-block-on-main-queue-is-never-execeuted)

```
-(void)didSelectDownloadButtonForCell:(FieldsCell *)cell{

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(ticktock) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    cell.shouldBeAnimating = YES;
    cell.ActivityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [cell.ActivityIndicator startAnimating];
    cell.DownloadBtn.hidden = YES;
    cell.PartialDownloadBtn.hidden = YES;

    HNField *field = [HNField fieldWithField_id:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:cell.tag]];
    NSString *xmlfile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[field.name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""],@".xml"];
    NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:xmlfile];
    __block NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];


    //load up core data with demo xml file
    dispatch_async(self.backgroundq, ^(void){
        NSLog(@"Block dispatched");
        HNArchivePointParser *aParser = [[HNArchivePointParser alloc]init];
        [aParser parsethisdata:data];
        NSLog(@"Parser has finished");

 //running simple loops works just fine.
//for (int i = 1;  i < 1000; i++) {
//    NSLog(@"%d - %@",i,cell);
//}


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           NSLog(@"THIS IS THE MAIN Q");
            cell.shouldBeAnimating = NO;
            [cell.ActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
            cell.ActivityIndicator.hidden = YES;
            cell.DownloadBtn.hidden = YES;
            cell.PartialDownloadBtn.hidden = NO;
        });
        NSLog(@"background Q completed");
    });
}

-(void)ticktock{
    NSLog(@"tick");
}
```

I lazily get my queue.

```
-(dispatch_queue_t )backgroundq{
    if (!_backgroundq) {
        NSLog(@"NEW");
        _backgroundq = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp....", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    }

    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        NSLog(@"RETURNED on Main Thread");
    }else NSLog(@"RETURNED on the wrong thread");

    return _backgroundq;
}
```

What could I be neglecting?

**UPDATE 1/23/14**
It is correct to assume `didSelectDownloadButtonForCell:` is always called on the main thread, I added some code to confirm it.
I also updated the code above and here is my log when I click one button and wait for it to complete before clicking the next.

```
2014-01-23 10:02:08.866[1362:70b] NEW
2014-01-23 10:02:08.867[1362:70b] RETURNED on Main Thread
2014-01-23 10:02:08.868[1362:f03] Block dispatched
2014-01-23 10:02:09.864[1362:70b] tick
2014-01-23 10:02:10.864[1362:70b] tick
2014-01-23 10:02:11.864[1362:70b] tick
2014-01-23 10:02:12.864[1362:70b] tick
2014-01-23 10:02:13.719[1362:f03] Parser has finished
2014-01-23 10:02:13.719[1362:70b] THIS IS THE MAIN Q
2014-01-23 10:02:13.719[1362:f03] background Q completed
2014-01-23 10:02:13.863[1362:70b] tick
2014-01-23 10:02:14.864[1362:70b] tick
2014-01-23 10:02:15.864[1362:70b] tick
more ticks.........
```

Here is the log when I click the same button and wait 2 ticks before clicking the next button

```
2014-01-23 10:10:32.484[1417:70b] NEW
2014-01-23 10:10:32.485[1417:70b] RETURNED on Main Thread
2014-01-23 10:10:32.486[1417:f03] Block dispatched
2014-01-23 10:10:33.482[1417:70b] tick
2014-01-23 10:10:34.481[1417:70b] tick
2014-01-23 10:10:37.304[1417:f03] Parser has finished
2014-01-23 10:10:37.304[1417:f03] background Q completed
```

The timer is on the main thread so obviously its locking up (UI become unresponsive too though my spinner continues).

Lastly here is `parsethisdata`in my `HNArchivePointParser` class which is intended to **only** be used in background threads.

```
-(void)parsethisdata:(NSData *)data{

    self.clientid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserId"];

    //create a MOC in background thread
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    self.MOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [self.MOC setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[app persistentStoreCoordinator]];
    self.theResponseId = 0;

    if (!self.parser) {
        self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data];
        [self.parser setDelegate:self];
        [self.parser parse];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post the console output that you're seeing -- like, do you ever see "Main Q" get logged? FWIW, it probably doesn't matter, but your lazy creation of `backgroundq` is not thread safe.  Assuming `didSelectDownloadButtonForCell:` is always called on the main thread, that shouldn't matter, but who knows? Also it's hard to say what, if any dependencies/interlocks are involved in `HNArchivePointParser`.  If that class isn't thread safe, or assumes it's main-thread only, or that it is used in the context of a runloop, that could explain the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: @ipmcc thanks for the reply! I've updated/added code to help shed more light. I'm really stumped as to why this code word one at a time but the main thread locks when I try to queue things up? I've lost a lot of sleep over this!!!

Comment: Are you using `performBlock:` for all interactions with that `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` MOC on the background thread? If you set an exception breakpoint do you hit it in the case where the callback never happens?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "interactions" please. While parsing I create `NSManagedObject`'s  for example. --> `self.aResponse = [HNDemoResponse createAResponseWithContext:self.MOC];
            self.aResponse.response_id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.theResponseId];` should I be using `performBlock:` any time I create an NSManagedObject and/or while assigning values to it like `self.aResponse.name = @"Kev";`?

Comment: I GOT IT! I didn't user `performBlock:`, though I'm still interesting in hearing about. Deep in my parser was 2 lines of code that were pulling two separate `NSManagedObjects` using my main threads MOC. gosh, I feel like an idiot now! I just changed it to use my threads MOC and all seems good!

Comment: As explained in the docs, all operations against a MOC of type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` must occur in blocks submitted to `-performBlock:` or `-performBlockAndWait:`. (See "Concurrency" here : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html )  If, instead, you want to just say, "I guarantee that all operations on this MOC will be done from one thread, and that's my responsibility" you should use `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` instead.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45954/discussion-between-kev-and-ipmcc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what's causing your troubles, but one thing's for sure: you should be doing all your work on `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` managed object contexts inside blocks submitted to `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:`.

If, instead, you want to just say, "I guarantee that all operations on this MOC will be done from one thread, and that's my responsibility" you should use `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`.

I can't speak to the reasons why it doesn't barf and die if you access it without using those (it would be fairly easy to check for,) but the [docs are pretty clear](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html) about this.

GCD will generally be pretty smart about these things. For instance, if you call `performBlockAndWait:` it will, in most cases, end up using the calling thread to do the actual execution, it will just wait until no one else is executing in that queue, so it's not like there's automatically some huge switching cost involved.

Assuming the MOC is private to that parsing operation, there's no reason not to just do the entire parse operation in a single block submitted to `performBlock:`.